# Sql query for Datawarehousing

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding SQL query for DWH. I have months and year column in my dimension table and sales value in my Fact table, I want to find the sales for the third quarter for a particular year. What would be the SQL query for this?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt. And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the comments. My question is generic sql not a database specific. This question was asked during one of the interviews to me. They gave the generic Dimension table schema and Fact table schema. I m curious to know what are the possible solutions. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fact.sales_value FROM fact_sales
INNER JOIN dim_month ON (... your join here ...)
WHERE
   dim_month.month IN ( 7,8,9 ) 
AND
   dim_month.year = <yourYear>
```

If you have more queries like that, you make consider a starflake-schema, where you have dim_month, dim_quartar, dim_year etc. instead of having month and year combined in one dimension table.

Comment: Thanks every1. This was also my approach. I hope it is correct as they did not specify any schema. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your fact table has your date column as a foreign key to your date dimension, you could directly filter by date.

```
CREATE TABLE Date (
    Date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    Year INT,
    Quarter INT,
    Semestre INT,
    FiscalYear INT,
    IsEndOfMonth BIT,
    --... other metrics
    )

CREATE TABLE Fact (
    SaleID INT,
    --... other metrics
    Date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Date) REFERENCES Date (Date))


SELECT
    *
FROM
    Fact F
WHERE
    F.Date >= '2018-10-01' AND -- No need to access the Date dimension in this case
    F.Date < '2019-01-01'
```

If your dimension table has a surrogate key and the fact is linked to your date dimension by this key, then the only possible filter would be by joining both and filtering the date table.

```
CREATE TABLE Date (
    DateID INT PRIMARY KEY, -- Auto-generated number, not related to the actual date information
    Date DATE UNIQUE,
    Year INT,
    Quarter INT,
    Semestre INT,
    FiscalYear INT,
    IsEndOfMonth BIT,
    Month INT,
    --... other metrics
    )

CREATE TABLE Fact (
    SaleID INT,
    --... other metrics
    DateID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (DateID) REFERENCES Date (DateID))


SELECT
    *
FROM
    Fact F
    INNER JOIN Date D ON F.DateID = D.DateID
WHERE
    D.Month IN (10, 11, 12) AND
    D.Year = 2018
```

Performance times would greatly depend on amount of rows, indexes, function calls and query complexity.

Comment: Thank you .. That was a nice and detailed answer !!